# PyQt5 Remove percentage label from QProgressDialog

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I wanted to remove the space that keeps the percentage number in QProgressDialog, when the prograss is indeterminate.

[image]

Comment: @LucasM.Uriarte Because they had a problem for which they found a solution on their own, and they want to share it with other people. The question form itself integrates an optional "Answer your own question" field.

Comment: It is perfectly ok. I was just curios, I have never seen such a fast answer from someone to a question they post them self. I know you can answer your own questions, I was just shock about speed

Comment: lol! Like @musicamante said, I took a long time to discover this simple case, so I decided to post here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the space, you can create a custom progress bar using QProgressBar widget, and set `setTextVisible(False)`:

```py
dialog = QProgressDialog('Progress', 'Cancel', 0, 0, parent)
bar = QProgressBar(dialog)

# Remove percentage text
bar.setTextVisible(False) 

# Set Indeterminate
bar.setMinimum(0)
bar.setMaximum(0)

# Set progress bar component to dialog
dialog.setBar(bar)

# Show dialog
dialog.show()
```

Comment: You don't actually need to set another progress bar, as the dialog already contains one. Just use `dialog.findChild(QProgressBar).setTextVisible(False)`

Comment: Cool! Can you answer it to the question?